# Программа аварийно завершается при импорте данных из .CSV файла в QAbstractTableModel по нажатию кнопки

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, csv

У меня есть таблица/представление QAbstractTableModel/QAbstractTableView, есть и делегат, есть кусок кода, который нормально импортирует данные из .CSV-файла, если его поместить в конструктор модели, то все работает: при запуске приложения появляется диалоговое окно и после выбора файла таблица заполняется значениями. вот этот кусок:

```
  TableModel::TableModel(QObject *parent)
    :  QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
  QString strFilter="*.csv";
  QString m_DataFileCSV = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0,
                                        QString::fromUtf8("Открыть файл"),
                                        QDir::currentPath(),
                                        "*.csv",  &strFilter);
  QFile file(m_DataFileCSV);
  file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);    
   /*считываешь построчно csv, рассматриваешь в цикле каждую строку.
   пробегаешь по всей длине строки, если находишь разделитель,
   вырезаешь столбец, добавляешь в структуру ColumData и  потом добавляешь ряд в TabelModel.*/
   QString line;
   QTextStream in(&file);
   while (!in.atEnd())
   {
     line = in.readLine();
     int columnsCount = 0;
     int beginColumn = 0;
     ColumnData appendedRow;
     for (int lineElement=0; lineElement = line.length(); lineElement++) // здесь в условие lineElement меньше или = line.length(), но я что-то никак не соображу как правильно оформить, т.к. если ставлю знак "меньше", то весь код после него исчезает ((
     {
       if ( line[lineElement] == ',') 
           ine[lineElement] = '.';
       if ((line[lineElement] == ';') && (columnsCount == 0) )
           {
             QString stringValue = line.mid(beginColumn, lineElement - beginColumn);
             double doubleValue = stringValue.toDouble();
             appendedRow.1Column = doubleValue;
             beginColumn = lineElement + 1;
             columnsCount++;
            }
            else {
                   if ((line[lineElement] == ';') && (columnsCount == 1) )
                      {
                        QString stringValue = line.mid(beginColumn, lineElement - beginColumn);
                        double doubleValue = stringValue.toDouble();
                        appendedRow.2Column = doubleValue;
                        beginColumn = lineElement + 1;
                        columnsCount++;
                       }
                       else {
                              if ((line[lineElement] == ';') && (columnsCount == 2) )
                                {
                                  QString stringValue = line.mid(beginColumn, lineElement - beginColumn);
                                  double doubleValue = stringValue.toDouble();
                                  appendedRow.3Column = doubleValue;
                                  m_DataOfMeashurements.append(appendedRow);
                                  break;
                                 }
                              }
                  }
                  if ((lineElement == line.length()) && (columnsCount == 2) )
                     {
                       QString stringValue = line.mid(beginColumn, lineElement - beginColumn);
                       double doubleValue = stringValue.toDouble();
                       appendedRow.3Column = doubleValue;
                       m_DataOfMeashurements.append(appendedRow);
                       break;
                      }
      }
  }
}
```

Так вот подскажите: мне необходимо  сделать  так, чтобы импорт данных происходил по нажатию кнопки "Open". Я создал функцию `void openFile()` в модели `tablemodel.h`:

```
#ifndef TABLEMODEL_H
#define TABLEMODEL_H


#endif // TABLEMODEL_H

#include 
#include "dspinboxdelegate.h"

class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    TableModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~TableModel();
    friend MainWidget;

    int             rowCount     (const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int             columnCount  (const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant        data         (const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool            setData      (const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
    QVariant        headerData   (int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags   flags        (const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    bool            insertRows   (int rowCount(), int rows, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex());
    bool            removeRows   (int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex());
    void           openFile();

protected:
    // структура для хранения данных столбцов
    struct ColumnData
    {
        double 1Column = 0.00;
        double 2Column = 0.00;
        double 3Column = 0.00;
        double 4Column = 0.00;
        double 5Column = 0.00;
        double 6Column = 0.00;
        QString color = "";
        QString comment = "";
    };

    QList ColumnData m_DataOfMeashurements; //ColumnData в угловых скобках, но я никак не пойму как их экранировать,чтобы текст в них не пропадал((. Список хранения записей
    QString m_DataFileCSV; // файл для хранения данных на диске
    ColumnData appendedRow; // добавляем ряд при импорте данных с CSV файла

    // Операторы для сериализации структуры ColumnData
    friend QDataStream &operator>(QDataStream &dataStream, ColumnData& rec);

signals:
   inline void valuesAssighnment(QList ColumnData ); // до сих пор не допетрил, как экранировать в коде угловые скобки. ибо тогда "съедается" ColumnData. inline вписал т.к выдавал ошибку что multiple definition of TableModel::valuesAssighnment()

};
```

и сделал в `tablemodel.cpp` реализацию этой функции (тот кусок кода).

А в `mainwidget.cpp` и `mainwidget.h` сделал вызов этой функции через сигнал:

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 


class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWidget();

private:
    QPushButton *openButton;
    QPushButton *addRowButton;
    QPushButton *removeRowButton;
    QPushButton *calculationButton;
    TableModel *m_model;

private slots:
    void openClicked();
    //void addRowClicked();
    //void removeRowClicked();
    //void calculationClicked();
};

#endif // MAINWIDGET_H
```

`mainwidget.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include "dspinboxdelegate.h"
#include 

#include 
#include 

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QTableView *m_table = new QTableView;
    TableModel *m_model = new TableModel;
    m_table->setModel(m_model);
    m_table->hideColumn(3);
    m_table->hideColumn(4);
    m_table->hideColumn(5);
    m_table->hideColumn(6);
    m_table->hideColumn(7);
    //m_table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    m_table->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    m_table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    DoubleSpinBoxDelegate *DspinBDelegate = new DoubleSpinBoxDelegate;
    m_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, DspinBDelegate);
    m_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, DspinBDelegate);
    m_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, DspinBDelegate);
    m_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(3, DspinBDelegate);
    m_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(4, DspinBDelegate);
    m_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(5, DspinBDelegate);
    m_table->setColumnWidth(0, 100);
    m_table->setColumnWidth(1, 100);
    m_table->setColumnWidth(2, 100);
    m_table->setMinimumWidth(318);// реализовать автоматическое расширение таблицы
     m_table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum,QSizePolicy::Expanding));

    openButton = new QPushButton("Open");
    //создание еще всяких кнопок

    QHBoxLayout *upperButtonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    upperButtonsLayout->addWidget(openButton);


    QHBoxLayout *lowerButtonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    lowerButtonsLayout->addWidget(addRowButton);
    lowerButtonsLayout->addWidget(removeRowButton);
    lowerButtonsLayout->addWidget(calculationButton);


    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(upperButtonsLayout);
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_table);
    mainLayout->addLayout(lowerButtonsLayout);


    connect (openButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openClicked()));

    setLayout(mainLayout);


}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{

}

void MainWidget::openClicked()
{
   QList intermediateValue = m_model->openFile();
   emit m_model->valuesAssighnment(intermediateValue); // тут m_model указал от балды, т.к.  valuesAssighnment() требуется член класса TabelModel, как правильно сделать не знаю.
}
```

еще в `tablemodel.cpp` добавил реализацию функции:

```
void TableModel::valuesAssighnment(QList importedValues)
{
  m_DataOfMeashurements = importedValues;
}
```

Немного информации:
данные модели хранятся в ``` QList``<ColumnData> ``` m_DataOfMeashurements`, где ColumnData структура, которая и есть ряды таблицы.

Чтобы передать данные при импорте из csv файла в таблицу мне надо эти данные передать в ``` QList``<ColumnData> ``` m_DataOfMeashurements.

После сборки приложения появляется виджет, в нем нажимаю кнопку "OPEN", появляется диалоговое окно выбора файла. Затем я выбираю файл двойным кликом и программа закрывается.

`Программа неожиданно завершилась.`

Подскажите что не так и  как с этим быть?

Comment: Дебагером определяется строчка, на которой происходит завершение? Программа возвращается из QFileDialog::getOpenFileName? Попробуйте очистить проект и пересобрать на всякий случай.

Comment: Да, определяется. Пока что ждал овета, тыкался, гуглил и продвинулся уже, до того, что добавил функцию 'signals:
   inline void valuesAssighnment(QList<ColumnData>)
{

Comment: m_DataOfMeashurements = importedValues;
}'
(обновил файлы в первом посте) где эта функция передает данные из csv-файла в QList<ColumntData> importedValues в переменную где храняться данные модели QList<ColumntData> m_DataOfMeashurments, но все равно программа крашится.
QDebugger показывает такое:
`void TableModel::valuesAssighnment(QList<ColumnData> _t1)
{
    void *_a[] = { Q_NULLPTR, const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&_t1)) };
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, _a);
}`
и стрелка на последней строке. Я так понимаю проблема в том что я в не суразно

Comment: реализовал передачу данных из csv файла, которая извлекается функцией из класса модели, вызванной функцией класса представления, которая потом передает сигнал(функцию) из класса модели, который должен присвоить данные из временной переменной в переменную,которая находится в закрытой части класса модели в которой храняться данные модели... понимаю что сумбурно, громоздко. Но это моя первая более менее полноценная попытка написания прогрграммы которая делает что-то большое, а не  передает значение из одного поля в другое... соответсвенео много ошибок вылазеет по ходу написания. так и учусь.

Comment: да, совсем забыл то что в 3ем коменте это QDebugger показывает в файле `moc_mainwidget.cpp` , функция `MainWidget::qt_static_metacall` и уровень 4, но для меня это уже темный лес.

Comment: Так, я тут решил попробовать собрать ваш проект и во всём разобраться и столкнулся с кучей опечаток, ошибок синтаксиса и прочего. Пока вы не выложите нормальный минимально компилируемый пример, боюсь толку не будет. Тот код, который вы выложили, вообще не должен компилироваться! (например, хотя бы из-за вот какой-нибудь такой строчки  `double 1Column = 0.00;` или вот такой `ine[lineElement] = '.';` или вот `QList intermediateValue = m_model->openFile();`)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего надо писать так:

```
void TableModel::valuesAssighnment( const QList & importedValues )
{
    beginResetModel();

    m_DataOfMeashurements = importedValues;

    endResetModel();
}
```